How to call suspend fun in async way from flow scope?
So I have never done something like this, so I have no clue which is the better approach.
Right now, I have a useCase, which returns with a flow. To keep it simple, I don't attach my code, but it is very similar to this.
class UseCase constructor(
    private val userRepository: UserRepository,
    private val carRepository: CarRepository
){
    operator fun invoke(): Flow<Result<UserWithCars>>{
        return flow {
            try {
                //UserRepository under the hood returns with a RxJava Single<List<User>> list
                // But I converted to suspend fun with await() fun
                val users = userRepository.getAllUsers().await()
                fetchUserCars(users)
            }catch (e: Exception){
                emit(Result.Error())
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun fetchUserCars(userList: List<User>){
        userList.forEach { user->
            user.cars = try {
                //REpository also returns with a Single<>
                carRepository.getCarsByUserId(user.id).await()
            }catch (e: Exception){
                emptyList<Car>()
            }
        }
    }
}

If I'm not wrong, the foreach will be executed in synchronously. I'm not sure, but I think, the foreach can be executed in async way, but I don't know how.
Back then, I used the ansyc{} fun , but I requires to be inside a Coroutine scope.
Previously, the User Single was flatMap-ed, and the cars was fetched to the user object.
return users.flatMap { user->
                    fetchCars(user)
                }


In the fetchCars() method, I basically mapped every userId to a Single<> which queries the cars, so I get a List<Single> and after that, I used RxJava Zip fun, but in this case, I'm not sure, how the Zip runs, so every Single will be executed each other, or simultaneously
So can I optimize it a little bit more, or is it fine right now?

What do you mean by "synchronously"/"asynchronously"? Do you mean you like to send multiple cars requests concurrently? Also, please note you never emit any users to the flow.

Yes exactly, I'm not sure, if the backend can handle it, but I'm interested in about how can I do something like that.
As I mentioned, the code what I attached is an example, and not the real code

Broot's answer is good as it allows you to await the Singles asynchronously, but it launches a new coroutine to await each Single.
I'm not that familiar with RxJava, but I think the following should work without launching any additional coroutines:
private suspend fun fetchUserCars(userList: List<User>) {
    userList
        .map { it to carRepository.getCarsByUserId(it.id) }
        .map {
            it.first.cars = try {
                it.second.await()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                emptyList()
            }
        }
}

The list of users is iterated twice: On the first iteration the Singles are retrieved (without awaiting their value, so this is fast and no coroutine is needed), on the second iteration await is called on each Single to wait for the value. This needs a coroutine, but it can be done sequentially in the same coroutine that the suspend function runs in because you want to wait until everything is awaited.
This is a similar to how the built-in joinAll works on a List<Deferred>.

Thanks, actually, I created two versions of the use case class, and one of them is similar to yours.  So if I understand your code, the map fun comes from the RxJava library, it's definitely similar to mines, maybe it's a little bit better than the first approach.

map belongs to the standard lib of Kotlin, like forEach. It returns a new list with the items replaced by the lambda's value. It effectively maps values from the list to new values, hence its name.

Actually, if you call the map in a Single object, it will use the RxJava, userList.map comes from kotlin library, but as the carRepostiory.getCarsByUserId() returns with a Single, the second map comes from the Rx library, but yes it is a good solution, thanks

No, in both cases map is called on List. Inside the list there may be a Single, but the map operation is applied to the List not the Single, so the stdlib Kotlin map function is used in both cases. Single also has a map function that has similar semantics (therefore the same name), but that is never used here, nor should it.

You are correct about using async, but you probably missed the fact you need to create a new coroutine scope to allow launching multiple children. Also, because we don't return a list of cars, but we add it directly to the user, we can use launch instead of async:
private suspend fun fetchUserCars(userList: List<User>){
    coroutineScope { 
        userList.forEach { user->
            launch {
                user.cars = try {
                    //REpository also returns with a Single<>
                    carRepository.getCarsByUserId(user.id).await()
                }catch (e: Exception){
                    emptyList<Car>()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Please note this may launch large number of parallel network requests. You can limit this number by replacing the coroutineScope with e.g.: withContext(Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(8)). However, because you use RxJava underneath, this may be not needed, as RxJava probably manages its own queues and thread pools.

Thanks, by this time I also found what I missed, but It's good, that you confirmed it.

I'm not proficient with RxJava, but shouldn't it be sufficient to first retrieve all singles and then await them in a separate loop? No additional coroutines would be needed then. I added this as a separate answer, please compare.

@Leviathan Yeah, I'm not very familiar with RxJava neither, but it makes sense.
